# Relationships in my table

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

I have db with 4 tables: users(pk), groups(pk), items and userToGroup. Added diagram:

[image: My diagram]

Does the relationships are ok? I remember from the past that it shouldn't be a circle relationship. Is it true? If it is, how can I change it to be ok?

Comment: It's a weird diagram. So, an item has a user and a group, but there's a table that has the user and group too. So, you could have an item that belong to group 1 assigned to a user that belongs to group 2. Is that your intention?

Comment: Why can an Item be related to a user or a group? Should that just be a group? Also I would suggest you keep your column names consistent across tables. UserID, GroupID etc. ID is not a good name because your entity name has to change names in other tables. Same thing with name. I would user ItemName and GroupName otherwise you will have to alias them evertime you query them.

Comment: Circle usually means extra information. Could you please explain what do groups and items mean in your DB? Do you have common groups that could contain both users and items?

Comment: To help you please explain the diagram.

Comment: It is not strictly _wrong_, but it does allow for some confusion.  It is clear that Users and Groups exist in a many-to-many relationship with UserToGroup serving as a bridge table.  Unfortunately, Items also could be used as a bridge table -- incorrectly of course -- but the structure implies the relationship.

Comment: Ok, I'll explain what I want to do: I want to create users and relate them to groups (many to many). Then create items that belongs to groups (one to many). I want to know who brings each item (so I related item to a user).

Comment: So you don't need the relation between Users and items.

Comment: Can the User only be associated with Items in a Group they are a member of? If so, the Items table should not have a foreign key to Users or Groups, but to UserToGroups. If a User can be associated with Items in a Group they are not a member of then the foreign keys look OK.

Comment: With your help I found out the problem I had and why the way I design it was wrong, so thanks. With MelgoV idea it solve part of the problem, but still not all of it (can't find the items of specific user). I decided to add a column to item table called UserName (string) and it has the username who should bring this item. This is not the solution I wanted but I see no other. Did you see what my problem was? Is there any better suggestion?